# C# using ClosedXML not able to read more than 2462 columns

Tags: c#, .net, closedxml

I have a hierarchical Excel file, there are more than 3000 columns. I created a C# console application to read the Excel using the ClosedXML library. But ClosedXML is reading only 2462 columns - the rest of the column's data is returned as empty responses.

This is the sample code I used to read the file:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook("Book1.xlsx");
var sheet1 = workbook.Worksheet(1);
var headers = sheet1.Row(1);
var headersCount = headers.Cells().Count(cell => !cell.IsEmpty());
```

headercount is always returning 2462 columns, is there any limitation with closedxml to read number of columns?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It could be something related to your excel file. Be sure it has no formatting, formulas etc. I have experienced it before, maybe it might be the case.

Comment: I verified again, it's not having any formatting or formulas. Even I tried with multiple Libraries like IronXL, EPPLUS none of them are returning more than 2462 columns. I don't understand the underlying problem